# Using mv to rename files on terminal ended up with lost files

Tags: macos, terminal

I'm on macOS Mojave 10.14.4, on a APFS SSD. Last week some students delivered me some image files over an image processing assignment. I have an automated routine on Matlab to grade the assignments, but it only loads files with a specific ".jpeg" extension.

Rather than rewrite my routine, I usually just rename the files (a mess of ".jpg", ".JPEG", ".JPG") on terminal. I'm used to do that on my University issued linux desktop. But that day I had my MacBook Pro with me, so I got them with it.

Alas, my terminal command "mv *.jpg *.jpeg" returned with a no such file or directory error, so I left this task for later. Earlier today I got to work after a three day weekend and when I opened the folder, I realized that about half of the files were missing.

My guess is that the mv didn't "fail properly" and, based on some thing that I've already looked around, may have lost the data for good! My Time Machine is at home, so it never got to back up those files.

I have already looked for possibly hidden folders where the files might have ended up, but no luck. Does anyone has any idea where the files may have gone? Or if they are truly lost?

Att.

Osmar

Comment: `mv *.jpg *.jpeg` does not rename all files ending in .jpg to .jpeg (DOS and Windows do have the rename command that does that) mv will move all its inputs except the last one to the last one. See [Unix Haters handbook page 189](https://web.mit.edu/~simsong/www/ugh.pdf). Yes you have lost data.

Comment: Ok, not too much trouble. It does work that way on Ubuntu though, and I just assumed it would be the same on my Mac. Thanks for the answer and the reference.

Comment: mv does not work that way on any Unix. The *.jpg and *.jpeg are expanded to actual file names before being passed to mv SO if you have a.jpg and b.jpg the shell expands the command `mv *.jpg *.jpeg` to  `mv a.jpg b.jpg`

Comment: Are you sure the files are missing? `mv *.jpg *.jpeg` will throw an error if there are more then two names after wildcard expansion (and the second name can even be a literal `*.jpeg`). So to loose files you would need to have exactly one file matching the `*.jpg` part and one (or none) matching the `*.jpeg` pattern, and then run the command again after the next `whatever.jpg` got moved into the directory.

Comment: Can you . run the command `find . -name "*.jpeg"` and report the output to us? This should find the files if they're somewhere in the proximity to where you ran this command.

Comment: time you do a mv like Los use the -I option it will ask you for each move

Comment: Thank you all for your input. Just to clarify: the Time Machine hypothesis from Bill Smith didn't work (as I expected). Multiple tries with the instructions from the comments of 'nohillside' and 'slm' were fruitless. Nevertheless, again, thank you so much!

Just one last, for Mark's last comment. Linux is properly named GNU Linux, where GNU is a recursive acronym 'GNU is Not Unix'. So yes, by what I learned, UNIX systems won't work that way, as you pointed out. But Ubuntu flavored GNU Linux will happily do that, as I already knew.

Comment: nohillside saw fit to delete my answer, where I acknowledge that the data was lost, so I'm adding it here, so the question can have closure.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a *directory/folder* of **JPEG** *files* that have either a **.jpg** and or **.JPG** *extension* and you want to change the *extension* to **.jpeg**, then in **Terminal**, use the following *compound command* after *changing directory* `cd ...` to the *directory* containing the **JPEG** *files*:

```
for f in *.[jJ][pP][gG]; do mv -n "$f" "${f%.*}.jpeg"; done
```

Answer (score -1):

Try completing your Time Machine backup. macOS uses the free space on your hard disk to do backups of changed/new files hourly and writes those to your backup disk when you connect to your Time Machine.

It's quite likely that if you do a Time Machine backup, then search for your missing files, you'll find them.

Good luck!